# How do you earn bonus Merit Stamps?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

Occasionally when turning in an errand, you'll earn a bonus Merit Stamp ("You earned X stamps... and 1 bonus!"). What prompts the bonus stamp?

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tested this personally, it is for every 10 errands and bounty hunts you complete.

Do note that the count for errands and bounties are maintained seperately and the bonus merit point is awarded for completing 10 errands or 10 bounty hunts.